# How to use ASP.Net MVC View .csthml as Angular View instead of .html

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ng-view

Im trying to use Angulars $routeProvider to load templates in to a container in a .cshtml file that is in my Views folder.

Im getting a 404 with this code i Angular:

```
.when('#/second',{ urlTemplate:"Views/second.cshtml",controller:"MainController"})
```

Angular can´t find the second.cshtml file.
Why?
is it not possible to use .cshtml files?

Comment: It is possible. We have written few Angular applications with ***.cshtml*** as Angular's view. There are few steps you will need to do. Let me wrote an instruction now, and then post here.

Comment: I posted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39922683/296861). ***FYI**: Angular 2 is right around the corer. You want to use Angular 1.5's component so that you can migrate to Angular 2 easily.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few steps you will need to configure in order to serve ***.cshtml*** to client.

I created a sample project called [AngularAspNet at GitHub](https://github.com/winlwinoonet/AngularAspNet).

1) Create ***App*** folder to host Angular Scripts. *You can name whatever you want.*

2) Place ***.cshtml*** file inside ***App/xxx/Components/*** folder. Ensure that property is set to content.

[image]

*I would like to place Angular View and Component (JavaScript files) together. The reason is it helps me find View and corresponding Component easily, when the project becomes more complex. So, rather than placing .js inside Views folder, I place .chtml file inside App (Angular Script) folder.*

1) Create a **web.config** with **BlockViewHandler** inside .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
  ...        
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" 
          preCondition="integratedMode" 
          type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
   ...
</configuration>
```

4) Create Controller and Action Method.

```
public class NgController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult RenderComponents(string feature, string name)
    {
        return PartialView($"~/App/{feature}/Components/{name}");
    }
}
```

5) Configure Route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Components",
    url: "{feature}/components/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Ng", action = "RenderComponents" });
```

### Credit

[Building Strongly-typed AngularJS Apps with ASP.NET MVC 5
by Matt Honeycutt](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/building-strongly-typed-angularjs-apps-aspdotnet-mvc5/table-of-contents)

[AngularJS & ASP.NET MVC Playing nice Tutorial by Miguel Castro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BWiqmoiWls)

Comment: What do you get out of serving the .cshtml file vs. having an .html file?

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamic language, so maintenance cost is very high. Using server-side ***cshtml*** somewhat solves the problem; I can create strongly-typed ASP.Net MVC helpers to render Angular bindings and expressions. I like **[Axel Zaratean](https://axelzarate.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/angular-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc/)**'s helpers; *unfortunately he stopped contributing to [his GitHub project](https://github.com/axel-zarate/Angular.NET/).* I uses his as a based and modified a lot based on my need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serve the `.cshtml` file directly.

If there is no server-side logic, you would need to convert the file to a `.html` file or if there is logic, you would need to request it using the standard MVC route way: `/MyController/MyAction`.

Comment: It is possible. Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39922683/296861).