# ASP.Net MVC Angular Routing Subfolders

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

My question is how do I route to sub folders (angular) to return HTML files in the views folder of a ASP.net MVC project.

Comment: You might be interested to read this answer - [How to use ASP.Net MVC View .csthml as Angular View instead of .html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39922683/296861)

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that for some reason I can't use the Views folder to store my html files to be served. I created a separate folder 'View' (without s) and put sub folders with .html files in it. Used the routing on Angular and they served.

I'm posting this to help other people find this solution quicker.