# How to add new html page in project ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I try to add new static HTML page in project, for this I added link from one page to new page:

```
<a class="contact__item-link" href="~/Views/Home/Faq.cshtml" target="_blank">FAQ</a>
```

Also created file in `Views/Home/Faq.cshtml`. It does not work

Comment: cshtml is not a static HTML page and it won't be treated as such.

Comment: Then what it sholud be?

Comment: `html`. and you may have to allow static pages in your route config

Comment: How? Please explain me. And how to set path in HTML template on another page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17949486/2084315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you cannot directly browse View in ASP.Net MVC. You will need ***Controller***, ***Action Method*** and ***View***.

*For example,*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Faq()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then you can use either

```
@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "Faq", "Home", new { target = "_blank" })
```

OR

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Faq", "Home")" target="_blank">FAQ</a>
```

***FYI:*** Although you can modify to serve cshtml file; it is not a recommended approach in regular ASP.Net MVC. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39922683/296861).

Answer (score 0):

- If you really mean `html` then it is `html` e.g. `foo.html` (or `.htm` if you want)
- `cshtml` is not "static" as stated in the comments. Unless your site is an ASP.Net [`WebPages`](https://www.asp.net/web-pages) web site, then `cshtml` (and `vbhtml`) "files" are *restricted* by default.

  - If you have an ASP.Net *Application* (e.g. `MVC`), then you *can* override this behavior (but likely not what you would want)

Hth.