# Cannot access JavaScript files inside View folder in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-bundling

I am trying to add AngularJS in my mvc project.

This is my bundle config

```js
  public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {

           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularjs").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                        "~/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"));

               bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appscripts").Include(
                   "~/Areas/app.module.js",
                   "~/Areas/app.component.js",
                   "~/Areas/app.routes.js",

     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appcomponents").Include(
      "~/Areas/Home/Views/Default/default.component.js"));
        }
```

_Layout.cshtml

```js
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appscripts")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appcomponents")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I am able to add `~/bundles/jquery`, `~/bundles/angularjs` and `~/bundles/appscripts`

[image]

but I am unable to add `~/bundles/appcomponents` and I am getting a 404 error for this script.

[image]

I also tried adding the script file directly in the _layout.cshtml

```js
<script src="~/Areas/Home/Views/Default/default.component.js"></script>
```

and I am getting the same error.

I am not sure why I am not able to add any scripts from the Views folder.

Can anyone please let me know how I can add this script file in the bundle config?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you add in what is in your `RouteConfig`?

Comment: public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: @YogendharReddy use the [edit] button, located under the tag list, to add that to your question. Comments aren't really intended for large blocks of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to security reason, `web.config` inside `View` folder blocks accessing files from browser. However, you can configure it to allow -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
  ...        
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.js" verb="*" 
          preCondition="integratedMode" 
          type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
   ...
</configuration>
```

[image]

*[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39922683/296861) is my answer similar to this question, but it is about cshtml file.*